# How to delete the image drawn in Canvas?

Tags: android

How will I delete the image drawn on my canvas if my code is this? Where will I put the delete process here? I've tried using the `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` but it is not working.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);   
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // nothing to do
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old thread I know, but I was mucking around with API fingerpaint demo and wanted to clear canvas but not fill with solid colour (I had a background). Building on @coder_For_Life22 answer above I included following method:

```
protected void clear(){
    Xfermode x = mPaint.getXfermode();
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
    mCanvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
    mPaint.setXfermode(x);

    //Schedule redraw()
    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with your Paint object..

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
canvas.drawPaint(paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC));
```

Comment: is it after this code?? public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

Answer (score 1):

```
canvas.drawColor(0xff000000);  // i can't see why it should not work except the clip rect mentioned below
```

or

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(0xff000000); // Specify the drawing color here
canvas.drawRect(0,0,w,h, paint);
```

always make sure that you did not set a clip that would influence the drawing behaviour.

Comment: hello! thank you :) where can i specifically place the canvas.drawColor? because i already try this but it doesn't work :(

Comment: if you place it as first command in your onDraw method it should work.

Comment: but when i place that on the first command of my onDraw this command is being ignored : public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);

  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
  paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

Comment: then delete the "Paint paint = new Paint();" and use your paint object instead.

Answer (score 1):

When `invalidate()` (or `postInvalidate()` from another thread) is called, `onDraw()` is subsequently called to redraw the *entire* area of the image. The `Canvas` object that is passed to `onDraw()` is backed with a bitmap that is already blank.

I realise that this doesn’t directly answer your question, but from reading your question I wonder if you’re misunderstanding the sequence of events that happen with `invalidate()` and `onDraw()`, together with the fact that you’re given a blank `Canvas` each time meaning you shouldn’t have a need to erase it.

It seems to me that what you're doing is you're trying to build up a `Path` vector representing the screen `MotionEvent`s. Looking at your code as it stands, it seems to me that you may want to erase all drawn graphics by clearing all segments from your `Path` object.

Comment: thank you so much. but i don't know why invalidate doesn't work or how will it work on my app. what i want is after drawing an image, that image drawn will be deleted once i tap the screen and draw for another image.